# My Plone product doesn't show up in the quickinstaller

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a Plone site with a traditional product `BaseProduct` (versioned directly in the `Products` filesystem directory of the Zope installation); the rest of the setup is `buildout`-based.

For a fork of the project, I need another product `AdditionalProduct`, which I made the same way (I know it's not the current state-of-the art method; but that's how it worked before for me ...).

Now I *was* able to install `AdditionalProduct` using the quickinstaller (for now it contains a single skin directory with a single template only, but this will change, of course).

Sadly, this ceased to work; the product is not shown in the quickinstaller anymore.  There is no visible error; I was able to `pdb.set_trace()` it during instance startup, and there is no error in the error.log either.

The `profiles.zcml` file looks like this:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="BaseProduct">
  <include package="Products.GenericSetup" file="meta.zcml" />
  <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="default"
      title="AdditionalProduct"
      directory="profiles/default"
      description="Extension profile for AdditionalProduct."
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
      />
</configure>
```

(Copied and changed from an earlier `AdditionalProduct` of another fork; I don't really understand that `"meta.zcml"` part.)

How can I debug this?

I'd be willing to "eggify" my product (`AdditionalProduct` first, since it has the problem; perhaps `BaseProduct` later as well), but I'm not sure about the amount of work, and a How-To would be useful ...

Comment: Sometimes a product disappear from the quickinstaller if you introduced an error in the profile. Go to *Plone* install products page (not ZMI!) and check the bottom of the page where you can see those errors.

Comment: @keul: You don't mean the quickinstaller (`portal_quickinstaller`), do you? I can't find anything there which looks like an error message.

Comment: No, from the Plone user interface.

Comment: I don't know what you mean; I see nothing in the `plone_control_panel` nor in `portal_controlpanel`; the product is not visible in `prefs_install_products_form` ("Add-Ons"). I couldn't find anything like `user interface` in the gettext catalog, so the best hint would be the ID of the page ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your product should have a `configure.zcml` file that includes your `profiles.zcml` with the following directive:

```
<include file="profiles.zcml" />
```

Is it the case ?

Comment: I wondered why the product was visible on my Linux box but not anymore on the Server; and indeed that file seems to have gone lost while merging...

Answer (score 3):

You can debug this by ruling out the following:

- The ZCML is not loaded (introduce a syntax error in profiles.zcml and
  restart Plone to ensure profiles.zcml is loaded.)
- You don't have the `'z3c.autoinclude.plugin': 'target = plone'` entry point (not applicable as you are not using a Python package)
- Your product is not loaded by Zope2 because it's not in the products folder, or has some related issue e.g. missing `__init__.py`.

Also you may not need the following, as it should already be included by Plone before your products is loaded:

```
  <include package="Products.GenericSetup" file="meta.zcml" />
```

(And `file='meta.zcml'` means "load meta.zcml instead of the default file name i.e. configure.zcml")

Lastly, I'd recommend creating a Python package (AKA "eggify"). See the following for an overview:

- http://blog.aclark.net/2015/06/01/plone-add-on-development-for-command-line-savvy-developers/

Comment: Apparently the ZCML is not loaded. I introduced the same error for both `BaseProduct` and `AdditionalProduct`; I saw the expected error for `BaseProduct`, which made the start fail, but not for `AdditionalProduct`. Of course it is in the same `Products` folder as `BaseProduct`, and it has a `__init__.py` file (which is executed, as I can prove by a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` line).  Where would I put this entry point?

Comment: Ok, found the entry point (`setup.py`). I have still no idea why the product is not used. Is there something more needed than a `profiles.zcml` to make it visible?

Comment: For the records - I meanwhile eggified my `AdditionalProduct`. Perhaps it's overkill, but I might eggify `BaseProduct` as well, and this might make much more sense.